# How to Remove double Characters

Tags: powershell

I am removing all special characters with hyphen which works perfectly however in some situations it leaves double or even triple hyphens.  I am looking for a way to remove the instances of the double or more hyphen usage.

```
$c = 'Aged Cheddar , White Wine, and Sweet Fig Cheese Spread Pinot Grigio & Fig'

$c = $c -replace '\W','-'
```

Output: `Aged-Cheddar---White-Wine--and-Sweet-Fig-Cheese-Spread-Pinot-Grigio---Fig`

Comment: change your regex pattern to >>> `'\W{1,}','-'` <<< so that it replaces "1 or more" items. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following after first replace:

```
$c = $c -replace '(-){2,}','-'
```

Your code will be like:

```
$c = 'Aged Cheddar , White Wine, and Sweet Fig Cheese Spread Pinot Grigio & Fig'
$c = $c -replace '\W','-' 
$c = $c -replace '(-){2,}','-'
```

The output will be:

```
Aged-Cheddar-White-Wine-and-Sweet-Fig-Cheese-Spread-Pinot-Grigio-Fig
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish that is to have the replace run twice. The first time replacing the special characters, and the second time replacing the two or more hyphens with one hyphen. The following code does that, but is probably not the most robust method:

```
$c = ($c -replace '\W','-') -replace '--*','-'
```

Which outputs:

```
Aged-Cheddar-White-Wine-and-Sweet-Fig-Cheese-Spread-Pinot-Grigio-Fig
```

Note: if that was going to be included in code that I was writing I would break that into two steps for readability, but that is a personal preference. An example of that would be:

```
$temp = $c -replace '\W','-' 
$c = $temp -replace '--*','-'
```

Here is a [good article](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) on using replace in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a single replace:

```
$c = 'Aged Cheddar , White Wine, and Sweet Fig Cheese Spread Pinot Grigio & Fig'
$c -replace '\W+','-'
```

OUtput:

```
PS C:\> $c = 'Aged Cheddar , White Wine, and Sweet Fig Cheese Spread Pinot Grigio & Fig'
PS C:\> $c -replace '\W+','-'
Aged-Cheddar-White-Wine-and-Sweet-Fig-Cheese-Spread-Pinot-Grigio-Fig
PS C:\>
```